# waveform does not work properly for some operations

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, waveform

i am newbie in vhdl, modelsim, waveform etc. i've developed a simple operational process and a testbench to test my operations one by one on modelsim waveform.

when i run at simulator i see there are some problems; at multiply operation result is not put to output variable (result_out1) although it is calculated correctly at temp variable (uQ2). furthermore mod and rem operations do not give any output.

although add, sub and div operations work as expected why mul, mod and rem operaions fail?

i am sharing my code and waveform result below.

my code and testbench are below;

```
 rns.vhd
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

 entity rns is 
      port(
           en: in std_logic;
           op: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
           reg_a_in: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
           reg_b_in: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
           reg_c_in: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
           result_out1: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
           result_out2: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
      );
 end entity;


 architecture behave of rns is     
      signal uA, uB, uC, uQ, uR: unsigned(8 downto 0);
      signal uQ2: unsigned(17 downto 0);
      signal result: std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
      
 begin
      
      process(reg_a_in, reg_b_in, op)
      begin
           uA <= unsigned('0' & reg_a_in);
           uB <= unsigned('0' & reg_b_in);
      
           if op = "000" then
                uQ <= uA + uB;
           elsif op = "001" then
                uQ <= uA - uB;
           elsif op = "010" then
                uQ2 <= uA * uB;
                uQ <= resize(uQ2, uQ'length); --uQ2(8 downto 0);
           elsif op = "011" then
                uQ <= uA / uB;
           elsif op = "100" then
                uQ <= uA mod uB;
           elsif op = "101" then
                uQ <= uA rem uB;
           end if;
                
      end process;
       
      result <= std_logic_vector(uQ) when en = '1' else (others=>'Z'); 
      result_out1 <= result(7 downto 0) when en = '1' else (others=>'Z');
      
 end behave;


rns_tb.vhd
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity rns_tb is 
end entity;

architecture behave of rns_tb is

    component rns is
        port(
            en: in std_logic;
            op: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            reg_a_in: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            reg_b_in: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            reg_c_in: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            result_out1: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            result_out2: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    signal en_sig: std_logic;
    signal op_sig: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    signal reg_a_in_sig: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal reg_b_in_sig: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal reg_c_in_sig: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  
    signal result_out1_sig: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal result_out2_sig: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    constant wait_period: time :=10 ns;

begin
    rns1 : rns port map(en=>en_sig, op=>op_sig, reg_a_in=>reg_a_in_sig, reg_b_in=>reg_b_in_sig, 
    reg_c_in=>reg_c_in_sig, result_out1=>result_out1_sig, result_out2=>result_out2_sig);
    
    process
    begin
    
        op_sig <= (others => 'Z');
        wait for wait_period * 3;
        reg_a_in_sig <= "00000011";
        reg_b_in_sig <= "00000010";
        reg_c_in_sig <= "00000101";
        
        wait for wait_period;
        en_sig <= '1';
        op_sig <= "000";
        
        wait for wait_period * 5;
        op_sig <= "001";
        
        wait for wait_period * 5;
        op_sig <= "010";
        
        wait for wait_period * 5;
        op_sig <= "011";

        wait for wait_period * 5;
        op_sig <= "100";
        
        wait for wait_period * 5;
        op_sig <= "101";
        wait;
                
    end process;
end behave;
```

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code in textform instead of screenshots, it's hard to work with this data.

Comment: i have just added my code as textform

Comment: Can you post the whole code, where does `op`, `reg_a_in` and `reg_b_in` come from?

Comment: i added full code @po.pe

Comment: Images of code don't allow problems to be replicated nor show as results of search by future readers. From the waveform portion on the image we see all ms_tb.vhd signals. Multiple driver resolution can cause 'X's. Provide a [mcve], here include the testbench, expected and actual results.

Comment: testbench code also added.

Comment: Signal assignment semantics, and incorrect process sensitivity list.

Comment: i am newbie in vhdl @BrianDrummond, i dont understand what you said. could you please give detail about the problem and how can i resolve it?

Comment: Please make this into a [mre] where you remove everything that works and is not needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I'd suggest to use only clocked processes until you fully understand how they work. But let's see if we can fix your problem.

The problem is with the sensitivity list of your process. The simulation tool will evaluate the result of the process whenever a signal in the sensitivity list changes. For all operations this is signal `op` that changes and the process re-evaluates `uQ`.

**Important note**: Sensitivity lists only serve for simulation purpose and signals are assigned **after** the process evaluation is complete.

The above means that in case of your multiplication, the `op` changes to `010` and the process evaluates

```
            uQ2 <= uA * uB;
            uQ <= resize(uQ2, uQ'length); --uQ2(8 downto 0);
```

but because signals are assigned after evaluation, `uQ2` will have the result of the multiplication but `uQ` is the resize of the previous `uQ2`. To fix this you can either...

1. Not use `uQ2` and directly write `uQ <= resize(uA * uB, uQ'length)`
2. Extend the sensitivity list with `uQ2` so that `uQ` is re-evaluated once `uQ2` got updated.
3. As correctly mentioned in the comment, if you need "signals" in a `process` that are evaluated immediately use `variables` instead of `signal` types.

The result assignment can be optimized and to be honest, I would't use `Z` in this case.

```
  --result <= std_logic_vector(uQ) when en = '1' else (others=>'Z');
  result_out1 <= std_logic_vector(uQ(7 downto 0)) when en = '1' else (others=>'0');
```

In general, this implementation has some pitfalls and you might should add some additional control signals or even make it a clocked process. Check if this solves your issue, I didn't test it and my brain is still in Christmas mode.

Comment: thank you very much @po.pe, you have enlightened me. when i've implemented your first suggestion, it's worked. but i wonder something; if there are mutliple lines in a process we always need clock-wise signal to refresh values on simulator to see new values? and as i understand, it evaluates each statement sequentially but not synchronously. it does not wait until end of current statement evaluation to proceed next one, right? as if it calculates each statement asynchronously, right?

Comment: The second and third paragraphs of this answer are inaccurate. The fourth paragraph has grammatical errors (*but because signals or assigned after evaluation*). The question doesn't provide "mod and rem operaions" expected results, what about those operations? You could also declare uQ2 as a variable in the process instead of a signal avoiding the signal update issue. Otherwise the fix works.

Comment: @user1155120 could you clarify what inaccuracy you're refering to and I'll update the answer accordingly. Of course you could add variables to the process, but I didn't want to overcomplicate things for someone who never used them... but for completeness I've added it